# PDO - Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine, zend-framework-2

OIá gente!

Estou tentando configurar um projeto em um ambiente Mac Yosemite. O projeto que pretendo rodar funciona normalmente em um Ubuntu.
Fiz a instalação do drive do PDO. No phpinfo está assim:

```
PDO

PDO support => enabled 

PDO drivers => mysql, odbc, sqlite, pgsql 


pdo_mysql 

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled 

Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 15d5c781cfcad91193dceae1d2cdd127674ddb3e $ 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value 

pdo_mysql.default_socket => /tmp/mysql.sock => /tmp/mysql.sock 


PDO_ODBC 

PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC) => enabled 

ODBC Connection Pooling => Enabled, strict matching 



pdo_pgsql 

PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled 

PostgreSQL(libpq) Version => 9.4.4 

Module version => 1.0.2 

Revision =>  $Id: af568c8ae63693bc2b766337bd4731078e62f9b4 $  


pdo_sqlite 

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled 

SQLite Library => 3.8.10.2
```

O meu doctrine.global.php está assim:

```
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '5432',
                    'user'     => 'USER_POSTGRES',
                    'password' => 'USER_PASSWORD',
                    'dbname'   => 'my_database',
                )
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

Mas sempre que rodo o projeto tenho o erro:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in PASTA_DO_MEU_PROJETO/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 PASTA_DO_MEU_PROJETO/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=loca...', 'postgres', 'postgres', Array)
#1 PASTA_DO_MEU_PROJETO/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOPgSql/Driver.php(46): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('pgsql:host=loca...', 'postgres', 'postgres', Array)
#2 PASTA_DO_MEU_PROJETO/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver->connect(Array, 'postgres', 'postgres', Array)
#3 PASTA_DO_MEU_PROJETO/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(429): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
#4 PASTA_DO_MEU_PROJETO/vendor/doctrine/ in PASTA_DO_MEU_PROJETO/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 912
```

Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: Precisa instalar o driver do pdo_pgsql proavavelmente  via linha e comando

Comment: Eu fiz isso. Ele já está habilidade no php.ini. Tanto que no phpinfo() ele já aparece. Mas por algum motivo o doctrine não está reconhecendo.

Comment: Você consegue fazer um exemplo simples com PDO/pgsql funcionar?

Comment: Sempre o mesmo erro.

Comment: Digita `php -m` no console e tenta localizar também a linha `pdo_mysql`.

Comment: Existem as linha pdo_mysql e pdo_pgsql

Comment: Você sabe se existe somente uma versão do PHP instalada na sua máquina? Já reiniciou o servidor web depois de habilitar o `pdo_pgsql`?